# ¿Cómo puedo combinar una variable de php a Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

he tratado de combinar variables de php en javascript, he leído en muchos foros que es complicado hacer la combinación de ambos pero sí se puede (según las respuestas). Mi problema radica en lo siguiente:

En mi código de php tengo una variable llamada $imagenes de tipo string  la cual quisiera poder utilizar en javascript, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
   $imagenes = "imagen1.pngimagen2.pngimagen3.png";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var img = <?php echo $imagenes;?>
</script>
```

No se si se pueda hacer algo como el código que ingresé, ¿alguna sugerencia?.

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿ya lo probaste? ¿cuál fue el resultado?

Comment: Si el problema es de conversión de datos obtenidos con PHP para ¿usarlos? con javascript, puedes colocar la información en un control HTML, y con javascript obtienes los datos. No estoy muy familiarizado con PHP y no comprendo porqué deseas que la información esté disponible en variables de javascript, pero yo intentaría este enfoque.

Comment: Si necesitas usar esa cadena de caracteres PHP, como cadena en javascript, solo te hace falta incluir las comillas antes y después de hacer echo a la variable: `'<?= $imagenes ?>'`.

Comment: Por lo visto sólo me faltaban las comillas simples al inicio y final, vaya algo  sencillo se me escapó xD

Comment: Hola @Iras, te dejé una respuesta hace un par de semanas que deberías considerar. Por desgracia la respuesta propuesta por Ricardo sufre varios problemas (incluso de seguridad, XSS por ejemplo) que podría darte problemas.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Efectivamente. Pasar el valor de variables de `PHP` a `javascript` es trivial (ojo el valor no las referencias ;-). Como también te han comentado. Tienes que tener en cuenta que si se trata del tipo string debes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
   $imagenes = "imagen1.pngimagen2.pngimagen3.png";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = '<?php echo $imagenes;?>'
</script>
```

Si por un casual  quieres pasar  el valor de tipo `array`... que lo supongo pues no me tiene mucho sentido el valor de `$imagenes`... deberías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
   $imagenes = ' "imagen1.png","imagen2.pn","gimagen3.png" ';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = [ <?php echo $imagenes;?> ]
</script>
```

Y si quieres pasar un `array` de `PHP` a un `array` de `javascript`:

```
<?php
   $imagenes = array( "imagen1.png","imagen2.pn","gimagen3.png" );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = [ <?php echo implode("','",$imagenes);?> ]
</script>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, tu ejemplo de array me gustó mucho y seguramente usaré tu idea, agradezco tu tiempo.

Comment: Como dato adicional, si utilizar lo del array mencionado desde PHP a javascript, te recomiendo no utilizar un foreach (por ejemplo, si lo haces de aquella forma tendrás una "," al final de sobra) sino utilizar implode de la siguiente forma:

**implode(",", $imagenes)**

Esta función va a concatenar cada uno de los elementos de tu arreglo con el primer parámetro que le envíes (en este caso ","), obteniendo un resultado mejor en menos líneas de código.

Comment: Pues efectivamente mucho más sencillo. Gracias por el aporte. Luego modifico la respuesta ;-)

Comment: Notese que para que funcione adecuadamente el 'pegamento' deberia ser **','** en vez de **,** Pero sip. Queda mucho mas claro.

Comment: **No os recomiendo usar este código**, sobre todo si el valor de la variable `$imagenes` no podéis controlarlo. La única forma segura de asignar valores a una variable javascript a través de PHP es usando [`json_encode`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44659/18608).

Answer (score 3):

Existen muchas maneras de hacer el trabajo, pero en todos los casos hay que tener especial cuidado con el escapado de las comillas. Sin eso se podrían producir efectos no deseados en la aplicación.

Podríamos usar [`addslashes()`](http://php.net/addslashes) para hacer el trabajo:

```
<?php
   $imagenes = "imagen1.pngimagen2.pngimagen3.png";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var img = "<?= addslases($imagenes) ?>";
</script>
```

Este método no sería completamente seguro debido a que discrepancias en el juego de caracteres (no usar `utf-8`) podría permitir el cierre de la etiqueta `</script>` originando problemas de seguridad ([XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)).

Para mejorar la seguridad y para dar soporte a datos arbitrarios (clases, matrices, etc) es mejor usar [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
<?php
$prueba = new stdClass();
$prueba->matriz = [
  'imagen1' => 'url1',
  'imagen2' => 'url2',
];
$prueba->imagen1 = 'url1';
$prueba->imagen2 = 'url2';
?><script type="text/javascript">
var datos = <?= json_encode($prueba) ?>;
console.log(datos);
</script>
```

Si `$prueba` es una cadena de caracteres `json_encode` entrecomillará su contenido y escapará cualquier comilla de su interior. Si es una matriz usará `[]`, o usará `{}` para clases/objetos, etc.

---

*TL;DR (demasiado largo, no es necesario que lo leas)*

Si pudieras tener problemas o discrepancias en la codificación de caracteres (el devuelto por las cabeceras del servidor no coincide con el indicado en el HTML o simplemente no usas `utf-8`) te recomiendo agregar el parámetro `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS` a `json_encode` de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
$prueba = new stdClass();
$prueba->matriz = [
  'imagen1' => 'url1',
  'imagen2' => 'url2',
];
$prueba->imagen1 = 'url1';
$prueba->imagen2 = 'url2';
?><script type="text/javascript">
var datos = <?= json_encode($prueba,
  JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
) ?>;
console.log(datos);
</script>
```

La seguridad de la función `json_encode()` es más que suficiente si todo está correctamente codificado en `utf-8`. El RFC indica que [por defecto se usa `UTF-8` aunque podría usarse `UTF-16` también](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), por lo que si se mezclan diferentes codificaciones de caracteres podrían escaparse incorrectamente una comilla para determinado juego de caracteres.

Comment: Por curiosidad. ¿Cuando dices "una mala implementación del navegador",a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: ¿Sabes de la existencia de algún bug documentado de algún navegador que haya consistido en ese mal funcionamiento que comentas?

Comment: Como comentaba inicialmente te preguntaba por curiosidad. Personalmente me parece un sinsentido programar aplicaciones web pensando en evitar "hipotéticos bugs de los navegadores". Es como desarrollar aplicaciones de escritorio pensando en hipotéticos bugs del sistema operativo o del gestor de ventanas. Me parece un argumento érroneo para defender el uso de `json_encode()` para pasar el valor de variables entre **php** y **javascript**.

Comment: Sobre la inyección de código javascript que pretendes evitar... `json_encode()` desde luego que vale (aunque no es el objeto de la pregunta), pero... ten cuidado con los errores de implementación del intérprete javascript, _no vaya a ser que funcione de forma errónea y la liemos_ ;-)

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios @RicardoFernandez , modificaré la parte final de mi respuesta para explicar algún uso más útil de las opciones de `json_encode` que propongo y eliminaré la referencia a malas implementaciones en los navegadores.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes enviar información de `PHP` a `Javascript` sin problemas. De hecho, la forma en que lo realizas es la adecuada debido a que `PHP` es un lenguaje del lado del servidor y `Javascript` un lenguaje del lado del cliente, no tendrás inconvenientes pues todo el código `PHP` se ejecuta antes que el código `Javascript`.

De hecho es bastante común combinar `PHP` con `Javascript/jQuery` y no está visto como una mala práctica.

Comment: Muy bien gracias por el dato y tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy fácil de lograr

```
<?php
   $ima = "imagen1.pngimagen2.pngimagen3.png";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = '<?php echo $im;?>'
</script>
```

como puedes ver no tiene complicación es lo mismo que usarlas en html usando `echo`