# Pasar variables de PHP a jQuery y viceversa

Tags: php, jquery

¿Cuál es la mejor manera?

He visto [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24445/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-combinar-una-variable-de-php-a-javascript) donde se pasan las variables de esta forma:

```
<?php
 $row= "pantalla";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var row = '<?php echo $row;?>'
</script>
```

También aplicable a arrays

```
<?php
   $row= array( "pantalla","chip","flex" );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var row = [ <?php echo implode("','",$row);?> ]
</script>
```

También he visto que se puede hacer con `json_encode($row)` pero no sé como función y en todos los sitios que he buscado las explicaciones son liosas.

Si yo tengo un array `$row[]`, al hacer `json_encode()` ¿cómo hago para usarlas en jquery? Es decir meterlo en una variable jquery y usarlo.

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA PARA AÑADIR MÁS DATOS:**

Pretendo hacer un autocomplete desde la base de datos.

Tengo un array bidimensional llamado `$data` y quiero enviarlo a jquery para usar sus valores como opciones para autocomplete.

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM piezas" );
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $data[$i]['codigo'] = $row['codigo'];
        $data[$i]['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
        $i++;
    }
    json_encode($data);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( function() {
        var autocomlpetePiezas = <?php echo $json_encode($data) ?>
            $( "#piezas" ).autocomplete({
                source: autocomlpetePiezas
            });
        });
    </script>
```

EDITO codigo original del autocomplete de jqueryUI:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Comment: Mira mi código. Necesitas entrecomillar la asignación de valor del `var autocomlpetePiezas = <?php echo $json_encode($data) ?>` como te puse en mi ejemplo, haciendo uso de `addslases()` y comillas delimitadoras.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para ponerte una solución ajustada a tu código. También he aprovechado para limpiar algo de código innecesario (la variable contadora `$i` y la asignación elemento a elemento).

Comment: ¿Qué campo quieres que te aparezca en el auto completado? ¿Nombre y/o código?

Comment: Tengo un input `<form>
     <input type="text" size="50" id="piezas" name="piezas" />
    </form>` para ello.

Comment: De tu base de datos obtienes los registros de una tabla y luego obtienes los campos `$row['codigo']`, `$row['nombre']` y `$row['id']`. ¿Todos esos campos quieres agregarlos a la búsqueda de auto completado de texto o sólo uno de ellos?

Comment: Buscar por nombre, pero conservar los otros datos, aunque supongo que eso a malas se hace buscandolos por el valor obtenido por el nombre.

Comment: Hecho. He modificado mi respuesta para agregar únicamente los nombres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para generar en un script PHP una matriz/objeto para ser usada en JavaScript puedes hacer uso de [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
$prueba = new stdClass();
$prueba->matriz = [
  'indice1' => 'valor1',
  'indice2' => 'valor2',
];
$prueba->propiedad = 'valor de propiedad';
?><script type="text/javascript">
console.log(<?= json_encode($prueba,
    JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
) ?>);
</script>
```

Con [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) codificas los datos en JSON para poder ser usados por JavaScript.

Aunque la seguridad de la función `json_encode()` suele ser suficiente, una mala implementación en el navegador o que cambiaran el modo por defecto podría ser un problema, por lo que es recomendable hacer uso de las opciones `JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS`. Sin estas opciones `</script>` sería convertido en `<\/script>` y con ellas se convertiría en `\u003C\/script\u003E`.

En mi código he usado una clase con una matriz y una propiedad para que tengas un ejemplo bastante completo.

---

Edito para actualizar mi respuesta a tu edición:

```
<?php
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM piezas" );
    $data = [];
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        /* Agregamos únicamente los nombres */
        $data[] = $row['nombre'];
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( function() {
    var autocompletePiezas = <?= json_encode($data,
      JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS
    ) ?>;
    $( "#piezas" ).autocomplete({
      source: autocompletePiezas
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: He añadido el código original del array que usa el autocomplete de jqueryui.

Comment: ¿Podrías prepararme un [MCVE](es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? (Con datos definidos, no obtenidos desde base de datos)

Comment: Ahora funciona correctamente. Hay alguna forma de abrir un chat privado par consultar unas cosas?

Comment: Cuando los comentarios se acumulan te sale un enlace a un chat, pero siempre puedes usar el chat de http://chat.stackoverflow.com invitándome a una sala que hayas creado.

Answer (score 1):

a mi humilde opinión, No te serviría más utilizar AJAX?

Tendrías tu script:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller.php', //Tu archivo donde estará tu consulta
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data); //Imprime tu arreglo, observa la estructura
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("Error al cargar el arreglo");
        });
</script>
```

Tu archivo php:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
                0=>array("id"=>"1","codigo"=>"a","nombre"=>"user1"),
                1=>array("id"=>"2","codigo"=>"b","nombre"=>"user2"),
                2=>array("id"=>"3","codigo"=>"c","nombre"=>"user3"));


    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Lo que quiere evitar es, precisamente, esa llamada HTTP adicional. Su método garantiza la disponibilidad inmediata de la variable en tiempo de carga.

Comment: O vaya, entiendo!
(Independientemente de que la llamada sea sincrona o asíncrona, no aseguraría esa disponibilidad)
Saludos!