# Pasar variable en ruta location.href

Tags: jquery, laravel

tengo un filtro que necesito pasar en un href.location.  Cuando entro por primera a vez a mi página, llego a traves de esta ruta **`{{route('area.add', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>$ar])}}`**

```
<form class="form-inline">
        <select id="area" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="1" @if($ar=="1") selected @endif>Administrativo</option>
            <option value="2" @if($ar=="2") selected @endif>Alimentación</option>
            <option value="3" @if($ar=="3") selected @endif>Bodega</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

A través de un sweetalert aplico el filtro y paso mi ruta, la cual si paso mi variable en duro **"ar"=>1** me funciona, pero obviamente la idea es que me rescate el valor que selecciono del combobox y quede en la misma página.  Como puedo reescribir **"ar"=>1** por esto **$(this).val()**

```
$('#area').change(function (){
            alert($(this).val());
            location.href='{{route('area.add', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>1])}}';
            swal({
                title: 'Filtros',
                text: 'Estamos aplicando los filtros, espere un momento.',
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                onOpen: () => {
                    swal.showLoading()
                }
            }).then((result) => {

            })
        });
```

Quizás sea mucho mas sencillo de lo que me imagino. Ayuda porfi, gracias

Comment: Has intentado hacerlo de la siguiente forma?? area.add ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + $(this).val() + '])}}';

Comment: Hola Jorge, si lo he intentado, tengo un alert que cuando presiono mi seleccion me trae el valor correcto, pero mi ruta se transforma en algo indecifrable, al poner "ar"=>' + $(this).val() + ', me trae como resultado en mi ruta %20+%20%24%28this%29.val%28%29%20+%20

Comment: los %20, %24, etc.. que te aparecen es la representación del simbolo en el navegador por ejemplo, %24 es un espacio vacío, %20 es $ es decir que tu código está mandando la info como si fuera texto plano y no está transformando las variables. Dado que estás tratando con JQuery lo que anexes en las comillas lo toma como un simple String

Comment: He editado mi respuesta y al final te he adicionado un link donde podrás observar bien como hacer el paso de información de una variable entre php → jQuery o jQuery → php. Espero te sirva.

Comment: La respuesta que te dieron no creo que funcione prueba algo así https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/351237/92278

Comment: Gracias, ya he solucionado mi problema y he publicado mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

*Dado que la orientación que requieres es mas por el lado de JQuery te dejo un ejemplo funcional en esta respuesta de como puedes acceder a los datos y como anexarlos a la información que quieras.*

*He modificado el HTML, pero la prueba la puedes realizar en tu proyecto modificando el **location.href** como te lo he demostrado aquí*

```js
var area = {
  add: 'prueba'
};
$('#area').change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
  location.href = '{{route(' + area.add + ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + $(this).val() + '])}}';
  alert('{{route(' + area.add + ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + $(this).val() + '])}}');
  /* swal({
      title: 'Filtros',
      text: 'Estamos aplicando los filtros, espere un momento.',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      onOpen: () => {
          swal.showLoading()
      }
  }).then((result) => {

  }) */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-inline">
  <select id="area" class="form-control">
    <option selected value="" disabled></option>
    <option value="1">Administrativo</option>
    <option value="2">Alimentación</option>
    <option value="3">Bodega</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

***también puedes ajustar el jQuery de la siguiente forma:***

```js
$('#area').change(function(ev) {
  console.log(ev.target.value)
  alert(ev.target.value);
  location.href = '{{route(' + area.add + ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + ev.target.value + '])}}';
  alert('{{route(' + area.add + ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + ev.target.value + '])}}');
  /* swal({
      title: 'Filtros',
      text: 'Estamos aplicando los filtros, espere un momento.',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      onOpen: () => {
          swal.showLoading()
      }
  }).then((result) => {

  }) */
});
```

Observando lo que reflejas en los comentarios, te dejo la siguiente referencia donde podrás apoyarte para hacer el uso debido de tus datos de PHP en js o JQuery:

[pasar-variables-de-php-a-jquery-y-viceversa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44653/pasar-variables-de-php-a-jquery-y-viceversa)

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: Muchas gracais por tu ayuda, a través de esta forma location.href = '{{route(' + area.add + ', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>' + $(this).val() + '])}}'; ya lo había probado, mi problema es que mi ruta me la devuelve de la siguiente manera http://127.0.0.1:8000/1012/detalle/%20+%20%24%28this%29.val%28%29%20+%20/sm

Comment: Te adjunté una url al final, donde puedes observar como hacen el paso de datos entre PHP y jQuery. Eso eso lo que necesitas en este momento.

Comment: Jorge muchas gracias, he modificado mi codigo y me ha funcionado lo que necesitaba

Comment: Esto no va a funcionar, `route` es un helper de laravel y se ejecuta en el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Al final he resuelto mi problema de la siguiente manera

```
$('#area').change(function (){
       //location.href='{{route('area.add', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>1])}}';
       //HE CAMBIADO MI RUTA A ESTA MANERA PARA QUE EL VALOR DEL COMBOBOX ME TOME COMO CORRESPONDA Y NO ANEXE DATOS BASURA
         url='{{route('area.add', ["id"=>$adm->id, "ar"=>"#AR#"])}}';
         url=url.replace("#AR#", $(this).val());
         location.href=url;
        swal({
            title: 'Filtros',
            text: 'Estamos aplicando los filtros, espere un momento.',
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            onOpen: () => {
                swal.showLoading()
            }
        }).then((result) => {

        })
    });
```