# Usar variables php en javascrip

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando usar variables de php en javascript, pero me esta siendo imposible

mi codigo js

```
 label: "transversales",
          data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(0, 250, 220, .2)',
          ],
```

Lo que me interesa es en data, cambiar esos numeros por variables.
He probado a hacer cosas parecidas a esta pero nada.

```
data: [$var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7],
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: OJO ya existe una solución a esta pregunta, la puedes consultar  
[aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/24475/115097)

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de como sean tus variables, podrás utilizar una función u otra para representarlos de forma más o menos amable para trabajar (por ejemplo con arrays deberás de hacer un print_r o un json_decode, etc...), pero en el caso de que sean cadenas, números, fechas, etc, puedes hacer:

```
data: ["<?php echo $var1 ?>","<?php echo $var2 ?>",...
```